# jQuery UI + Bootstrap + noConflict results in "data is not a function" (tooltip)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, tooltip

I had to fix a conflict between jQuery UI and Bootstrap because I need both tooltip functions.

So this is what I did:

Including:

1. jQuery-1.7.2.min.js
2. UI stuff
3. Bootstrap (v3.1.1 minified)
4. resolve Conflict js
5. another JavaScript which calls the Bootstrap tooltip

This is my fix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Tooltip
    var bootstrapTooltip = $.fn.tooltip.noConflict(); // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
    $.fn.bootstrapTooltip = bootstrapTooltip;       // give $().bootstrapTooltip the Bootstrap functionality
});
```

This is my call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.icon-tooltip').bootstrapTooltip();
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<a onclick="return false;" rel="nofollow" href="" class="icon-tooltip"
    title="{% trans from "...." %}landingpage......
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-placement="bottom"
    data-html="true">
    <i class="icon icon-help-circled"></i>
</a>
```

What happens:
The tooltip is shown (well formatted) when the user hovers over `a.icon-tooltip` but on leaving the elements, it returns this error:

> TypeError: a(...)this.type.data is not a function

This is the position in Bootstrap:

```
var c=b instanceof this.constructor?b:a(b.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data("bs."+this.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to same name of plugins "Tooltip" in both. You can fix it by renaming the function name in jQuery UI using **$.widget.bridge**

Check http://www.mycodezone.com/fix-bootstrap-tooltip-and-jquery-ui-tooltip-conflict/ 
for full details. I have fixed my same issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to initialize tooltips and solve the `TypeError: "[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]".tooltip is not a function` error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
});
```

This example works for me at local:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Snippet Bootstrap grid</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
       <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <br/>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip">Click it!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(function () {
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Change the path to your bootstrap location. I hope it helps you